# Why is the C++ standard library aligning large string buffers to 32 bytes?

Tags: c++, std

I'm decompiling a binary built in C++ and have noticed that upon allocation and reallocation strings buffers are being aligned to the nearest 32 bytes when the buffer size ('alloc_bytes') is >= 0x1000. Here is my decompiled code illustrating this:

```
if (alloc_bytes < 0x1000)
{
    new_char_buffer = STD__allocate_bytes(alloc_bytes)
}
else
{
    void *new_buffer_start = STD__allocate_bytes(alloc_bytes + 0x20 + 0x07)

    new_char_buffer = new_buffer_start + 0x20 + 0x07
    new_char_buffer = new_buffer_start & 0xffffffffffffffe0 // round to lower 0x20
    *(new_char_buffer -0x08) = new_buffer_start // guaranteed valid memory after rounding because we allocated 0x20 (32) plus an additional 0x07 (7)
}
```

Here, if alloc_bytes is big enough, the beginning of the string's buffer is rounded to the lower 0x20 bytes and then the "real" beginning of the buffer is stored behind it. This just seems like a waste of space to me, because I don't understand any possible reasons aligning the beginning of the string's buffer like this could present any performance improvements. Is there any benefit to aligning a buffer like this, or is there just more context needed to understand the reasoning?

Comment: Off the top of my mind, this could be because it guarantees SIMD-friendly alignment, and large buffers are likely to be used in auto-vectorizable loops.

Comment: What compiler, OS? Where is this code from, what function?

Comment: This isn't "the C++ standard library" doing this. It is one detail of one implementation of that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know the official reason your compiler/library behaves this way, I can certainly see an immediate benefit: SIMD.

**S**ingle **I**nstruction **M**ultiple **D**ata instructions are operations that allow you to get very cheap parallelism. However, they do have some requirements before you, or more likely your compiler, can make use of them effectively.

One of those requirements is that loading memory in SIMD registers requires that the memory being loaded be more strictly aligned than for regular single-value operations.

Large buffers like that are very often used in algorithms that can make use of these instructions, and tend to see bigger benefits than smaller ones.

Also, since the buffer is already fairly large, the "waste" is proportionally very small. Wasting a small amount of memory to ensure that computations can be done 4* times faster sure sounds like a reasonable tradeoff to me.

**N.B.** It's not actually 4 times. Auto-vectorized loops typically have a prefix and postfix section to deal with misaligned data, so the real gain is just skipping the prefix and jumping straight to the vectorized loop. But these technicalities don't really matter as far as your question goes.